# Count Integer partitions possible for a range

Tags: algorithm

Problem Statement:

You are given two numbers, namely A and S. Write a program to find the number of ways in which the numbers that are greater than or equal to S can be added to get the sum A. Print the result as modulo 10^9+9.

e.g. If A is 3 and S is 1 then there are three ways to achieve A=3 using numbers greater and equal to S=1. Solutions are <1,1,1>, <1,2> and <3>.
For A=9 and S=3 the solutions would be <3,3,3>, <3,6>, <4,5> and <9>. Total 4 ways to get 9 using number greater than equal to 3.

I have used below approach.

1. Check if (S>A/2) then there is only one solution possible. e.g if A=9 and 
   S=5 then only one solution is possible that is <9>.
2. If condition 1 is not true and create a list and store all i that are 
   S<=i<=A/2 in the list.
3. For each number i in the list.

   3.1. While A>=i

   3.1.1. Decrement A by i.

   3.1.2. If A>=i then increment count(count stores the total         permutations and is 
      initially set as 1).

   3.1.3. Else come out of while loop.

This approach has quadratic time complexity. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Let's assume A >= S. The maximum number of integers you can have is k = floor(A/S) >= 1, and the minimum is 1.

Let's consider a set of r integers, 1 <= r <= k. How many of these are there?

Think of it like this. First create r integers all equal to S. Then we just need to count the different ways of assigning the leftover x = A - r*S to these r integers.

This is a well known problem (distributing x identical objects among r identical groups). This is the integer partition problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069639/partition-with-minimum-size-of-parts/2069824

Comment: @DaveGalvin thanks for the wikipedia link. For A=9 and S=3 solutions would be <3,3,3>, <3,6>, <4,5> and <9>. But using the approach you specified my k=floor(9/3)=3. Set of integers r would range from 1 to 3. This way I would get only the solutions <3,3,3>, <3,6>. how would I get the 4th solution <4,5>?

Comment: @jaikishan_gurav No, for r=2 you start with <3,3> with 3 left over, then count the number of distinct ways to allocate those three balls to two bins. That gives you 3,0 and 2,1. Then add these to <3.3> gives you <6,3> and <5,4>. The hard part is counting the number of ways to allocate identical balls to identical bins.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using dynamic programming. The problem is similar to coin change problem where sum is total amount we have and d,d+1,d+2,..,sum are coins available to us to achieve sum. Below is the java code that i wrote.

```
private static int countPartitionsDP(int d, int sum){
    if(d>sum/2)
        return 1;
    if(d>sum)
        return 0;
    int coins=sum-d+1;
    int[][] dp=new int[coins][sum+1];
    for(int i=0;i<coins;i++){   //for sum=5 and d=2 number that we use to achieve sum is 2,3,4,5 i.e (i+d).
        for(int j=0;j<=sum;j++){
            if(j==0)    //sum=0 can be achieved in 1 way. dp[i][0]=1
                dp[i][j]=1;
            else if(i==0){
                if(j<(i+d)){    //if current sum j is less than current value of d i.e.(i+d).
                    dp[i][j]=0;
                }else{
                    dp[i][j]=dp[i][j-i-d];  //if sum is greater than current value of d then dp[i][j]=dp[i][j-d]
                }
            }else if(j<(i+d)){
                dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j];
            }else{
                dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j]+dp[i][j-i-d];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[coins-1][sum];
}
```